# Some newbie questions about Java EE

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web

I am totally new to Java EE. So pardon me if this is too naive a question.

There're so many `concepts/jargon/specifictaion` in the world of Java Web development. So I am bit lost. Below are my questions:

- Do I must use Java EE SDK to develop web applications? Can Java SE SDK do that?
- I just downloaded and extracted the [Java EE SDK 7u1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html). There's only a single folder named `glassfish4` after extraction. I heard that Java EE SDK is a superset of Java SE. So I am expecting some extra `*.jar` files containing some new APIs. But where are they?
- What's the logical hierarchy Java web technology? It seems everything is based on `Servlet`.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should refer to tutorials, documentations, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java EE is a set of specifications and APIs that define the standards which form Java EE. As such Java EE is *not* a superset of Java SE which defines the language and standard libraries, but just is built on top of it. Additionally, besides the APIs there is no SDK as such. Just choose an implementation (most people use an application server like Glassfish, JBoss/Wildfly, Websphere etc.) and use that.

If you just want to download the API jars, check the various respositories on the net, e.g. Maven Central etc. The most basic API jar would be [javaee-api-7.0.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0). There are a couple of other jars but which you need to reference in your application depends on what you need and which Java EE implementation/provider you use.

Comment: Thanks. So my understanding is application servers like Glassfish **implement & expose** the APIs defined in Java EE. And these APIs are implemented through Java languages and standard libraries, which is defined in Java SE. So Java EE is a higher level business API targeting some enterprise applications.

Comment: @smwikipedia that sounds about correct.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the EE SDK for JavaEE development. It's just a glashfish server and some other tools provided by oracle to enable you to run EE applications. 
Any other application server would work just as well.
Depending on your application server, you just package your class files into archives with a deployment descriptor and deploy them to your server, where the EE components are executed.

Since you seem to target web development: Take a look at Apache Tomcat!
It's a EE Web-Container implementation, which allows you to run Servlets and components built on top (JSF, JSPs).
You do not need a fully blown application server for web development. Glasfish seems to be a bit of an overkill for your use case, as you are not looking to run Enterprise Java Beans.
Refer to http://tomcat.apache.org/

Comment: I suppose that if I want to compile some code using the Java EE API, then I need to reference some Java EE libraries. Are those libraries contained in Java EE SDK or somewhere else?

Comment: I never said it was a fully standard compliant application server, but much rather an implementation allowing you to run the Web-Tier components of the EE specification.